# If an independent clause stands on its own, is it still considered a clause?

Tags: grammar, terminology, independent-clauses

There are several definitions related to clauses in my textbook that am a little confused about, and I would greatly appreciate some clarification.

Here are the definitions:

1. *Clause*. A group of words which contains a subject and a verb but is in itself not a complete sentence, but a part of a complex or compound sentence.
2. A  *complex sentence* is a sentence which contains at least one dependent and one independent clause.

   > While we were away, our house was robbed.
3. An independent clause is a main clause, one that is not subordinate.

In the example given in definition 2, we have a dependent clause ("While we were away") and an independent clause ("our house was robbed.") It seems to me that the independent clause can stand on its own as a sentence ("Our house was robbed.")

However, it looks like based on definition 1, this would not qualify as a clause, since it **is** itself a complete sentence and is **not** part of a complex or compound sentence.

Is it correct to say that when an independent clause stands on its own, it is not considered a clause? If so, is it considered anything besides "a sentence"?

Thanks!

Comment: It's considered a clause even if it *doesn't* stand on its own. Both dependent and independent clauses are still clauses. (The first definition you give is wrong. It looks to me as if it was supposed to be defining ***dependent*** *clause* and the first word was mistakenly omitted.)

Comment: If removed from the sentence, "our house was robbed" could stand alone as a main clause, but in the sentence "While we were away, our house was robbed", it is just **part of** a larger clause. Compare "Ed said he was hungry", where "he was hungry" could _potentially_ stand alone as an independent clause, but in that sentence it is actually a dependent (subordinate) clause. Thus, it's important to distinguish the role of a particular sequence of words in a sentence from the role those words could potentially play elsewhere

Comment: @JasonBassford Would you say, then, that he sentence "I am." consists of one independent clause? I've always thought of a verb and its subject with no subordinate clauses or phrases as a 'sentence' rather than a 'sentence consisting of a single clause'; have I misunderstood the defintion of 'a sentence' all these years?

Comment: "I am" is a sentence consisting of a single clause. What else could it be?

Comment: @BoldBen A sentence always has at least one clause. That's how both *clause* and *sentence* are defined. A sentence fragment, on the other hand, doesn't need to have a clause at all—but neither is it a complete sentence in a strict sense. *I am.* That is both a single clause ***and*** a sentence. Are you suggesting it's something else?

Comment: @JasonBassford My understanding was that a clause is a part of a sentence which, in itself, has the structure of a sentence. This meant, to my understanding, that a sentence which cannot be split into clauses and/or phrases (like "I am" or "He runs quickly") is not a clause but a sentence. Your definition implies that _all_ sentences consist of at least one clause and that the words which form the simple sentence also form the clause it consists of. It's quite a subtle distinction which I can accept but to which I had not, previously, been exposed.

Comment: @BoldBen A sentence (by normal definition) must contain a subject and a predicate. That's the same thing as an independent clause. A sentence, therefore, is *at least* an independent clause. If you want to say that it is somehow more than that—because it starts with a capital letter and ends with a punctuation mark—that's fine. But that veers into style as opposed to grammar.

Comment: @JasonBassford That makes sense, although I would suggest that means that we speak in clauses and only use sentences when we write.

Comment: @BoldBen Interesting. I suppose you could look at it that way. Although we actually say "speak in complete sentences" not "speak in complete clauses." So, at least in terms of the wording we normally use, that wouldn't be the standard terminology.

Answer (score 1):

An independent clause, by definition, can stand alone as a sentence.

By definition, a sentence must have at least ONE independent clause to be considered a sentence.

A SIMPLE sentence has ONE and ONLY ONE independent clause.

A COMPLEX sentence has ONE independent clause and at least one dependent clause.

A COMPOUND sentence has TWO or more independent clauses.

A COMPLEX-COMPOUND sentence has TWO or more independent clauses with at least ONE dependent clause.